# Autocomplete return type of method in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

Is there a shortcut to get autocomplete of variable type being returned as result of a method call? ( instead of using var )

for example I know the function GetPerson(3); would return the person by id, how do I get the full type name including the namespace ?